# Amazon web service Data pipeline

Tags: amazon-web-services, pipeline

Can we use existing ec2 instance details while configuring data pipeline? If it is possible then what are the ec2 details that we need to provide while creating a pipe line?

Comment: what do you mean by 'existing ec2 instance details'?

Comment: I have already created one ec2 instance and it is in running state. I want to use that instance for all the data pipeline activities without creating new instance each and every time while creating new data pipelines.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it is possible. According to AWS support.

"You can install Task Runner on computational resources that you manage, such as an Amazon EC2 instance, or a physical server or workstation. Task Runner can be installed anywhere, on any compatible hardware or operating system, provided that it can communicate with the AWS Data Pipeline web service.

This approach can be useful when, for example, you want to use AWS Data Pipeline to process data that is stored inside your organization’s firewall. By installing Task Runner on a server in the local network, you can access the local database securely and then poll AWS Data Pipeline for the next task to run. When AWS Data Pipeline ends processing or deletes the pipeline, the Task Runner instance remains running on your computational resource until you manually shut it down. The Task Runner logs persist after pipeline execution is complete."

I did this myself as it takes a while to get the pipeline to start up, this start up time could be 10-15 minutes depending on unknown factors.

http://docs.aws.amazon.com/datapipeline/latest/DeveloperGuide/dp-how-task-runner-user-managed.html